# Extracting lines from a file containing keywords that are present in another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

`File1` (keywords present in it (after 2nd comma) for picking Ex: GOLD, BRO, ...)

`File2` (extraction of lines from here)

```
File1: 
ABC,123,GOLD,20171201,GOLDFUTURE
ABC,467,SILVER,20171201,SILVERFUTURE
ABC,987,BRO,20171201,BROFUTURE

File2:
XYZ,32,RUBY,20171201,RUBY  
XYZ,33,GOLD,20171201,GOLD
XYZ,34,CEMENT,20171201,CEMENT
XYZ,35,PILLAR,20171201,pillar  
XYZ,36,CNBC,20171201,CNBC
XYZ,37,CBX,20171201,CBX
XYZ,38,BRO,20171201,BRO
```

I want Linux commands(awk-sed-cat-grep etc) to get output file:
which is:

```
XYZ,33,GOLD,20171201,GOLD
XYZ,38,BRO,20171201,BRO
```

I have found commands online:

1. `grep -F -f File1 File2`
2. `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} ($NF in a)' File1 File2`
3. `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} ($0 in a)' File1 File2`
4. `diff File1 File2`

In the point 3. I am picking up whole lines from `File1` for comparison, is there any way to pickup a keyword after comma? Or is there any way to insert File separator in the `awk` command of point 2.

Comment: what are the rules to get the output file?

Comment: you can change the 3rd command to suit your case.. use `,` as delimiter and use 3rd field instead of entire line as key.. see http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ for some details on this

Comment: and I think we should do a community wiki to create a canonical answer for such questions.. not able to find exact duplicate for this question, but creating one Q&A with different variations can help to close all such questions :)

Comment: @Sundeep thats what I have asked.. How do i use delimiter in it ? I tried but it gives error ? using 'awk -F "," ' but this is not working correctly.

Comment: show us complete command you tried and also copy paste the error you got..

Comment: @Sundeep Agreed to create community wiki for such questions.

Comment: I believe that's what "stackoverflow documentation" was intended to provide. In the mean time, answers are still valid, and can be collapsed with duplicate identification as time goes by. @sumit, what does "not working correctly" mean? What exactly did you try using `awk -F` ? Include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$3];next} ($3 in a)' File1  File2
```

Comment: You don't actually need to *set* `a[$3]` to anything. Simply mentioning it is enough to cause the key to exist in the array, which is all you need for `$3 in a`.

Comment: @ghoti, thanks for letting me know sir, done changed it now.